# Extract the first num in list R

Tags: r, list

I have a list in R of over 1000 numeric values.
The sample data looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioeri.jpg)

I want to create 2 new lists. 1 list containing only the first number in this list, 0.663, 0.663, and 0.319. 2 list containing 0.337, 0.337, and 0.681. How can I do that?

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `do.call` with `rbind` to get matrix and split the the matrix column wise with `asplit`.

```
list2 <- asplit(do.call(rbind, listR), 2)
```

Similarly, you can also do -

```
list3 <- asplit(do.call(cbind, listR), 1)
```